# == in php causing false positives when variable is zero

Tags: php

I have the strangest php behavior I've never noticed before:

```
$array =array(0,1,2, 'parent');
   foreach ($array as $value)
{
    if ($value=='parent')
    {
        echo $value;
        echo '<br>';
        continue; 
    }

}
exit;
```

Will return

```
0
parent
```

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why it matches the 0 to the string 'parent'?

Comment: Read the relevant section of the PHP documents on [loose comparisons and typecasting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: try to var_dump($value);instead of echo. You will get clearer picture. As @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams "Because that's how PHP rolls: Like a square wheel."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what Mark said but to expound, 0 is a number so the == operator casts the 'parent' string to a number, which gives 0. The == operator does not care about type. So they match.

Comment: crazy. all these years I never ran into.

Comment: yeah, that's why you see === used a lot, so you don't get caught by a type mistake. you can always cast to string/number.

Answer (score 1):

The "==" operator in php does not compare the type of the objects, it converts the objects to another type. So in your case you are comparing a numerical object with a string object. So it changes the type of your string 'parent'. Since that string does not contain any numerical value it probably changes it to 0. 
See 
http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php  and
http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion
for more explanations